# Displaying a popup window from action toolbar on a compiled PyQt4 Qt Designer

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qt-designer

So, i tried to build an app and struggling on how to connect an action to another dialog window. I searched for it but only found a solution for a window that wasn't built with Qt Designer. I designed it with Qt Designer and compiled the .ui to .py format.

This is my first window:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'home.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.11.4
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from howto import Ui_HowToDialog

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_HomeWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, HomeWindow):
        HomeWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("HomeWindow"))
        HomeWindow.resize(1106, 259)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("Consolas"))
        HomeWindow.setFont(font)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8(":/resources/plottwist.png")), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        HomeWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
        HomeWindow.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(HomeWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.horizontalLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout"))
        self.homeBrowser = QtGui.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("Consolas"))
        self.homeBrowser.setFont(font)
        self.homeBrowser.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("homeBrowser"))
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.homeBrowser)
        HomeWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(HomeWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        HomeWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.homeToolbar = QtGui.QToolBar(HomeWindow)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("Consolas"))
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.homeToolbar.setFont(font)
        self.homeToolbar.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.homeToolbar.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.homeToolbar.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonTextUnderIcon)
        self.homeToolbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("homeToolbar"))
        HomeWindow.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.LeftToolBarArea, self.homeToolbar)
        self.actionOpenDataset = QtGui.QAction(HomeWindow)
        icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8(":/resources/dataset.png")), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.actionOpenDataset.setIcon(icon1)
        self.actionOpenDataset.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("actionOpenDataset"))
        self.actionHowTo = QtGui.QAction(HomeWindow)
        self.actionHowTo.triggered.connect(self.showHowto)
        icon2 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon2.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8(":/resources/howto.png")), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.actionHowTo.setIcon(icon2)
        self.actionHowTo.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("actionHowTo"))
        self.actionAbout = QtGui.QAction(HomeWindow)
        icon3 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon3.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8(":/resources/about.png")), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.actionAbout.setIcon(icon3)
        self.actionAbout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("actionAbout"))
        self.homeToolbar.addAction(self.actionOpenDataset)
        self.homeToolbar.addAction(self.actionHowTo)
        self.homeToolbar.addAction(self.actionAbout)

        self.retranslateUi(HomeWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(HomeWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, HomeWindow):
        HomeWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("HomeWindow", "Plot Twist", None))
        self.homeBrowser.setHtml(_translate("HomeWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'Consolas\'; font-size:7.5pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p align=\"justify\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:14pt; font-weight:600;\">Data Visualization is as important as it sounds, you can visualize your data with this app just by inserting any dataset you want. For more detailed instructions, simply go to How To icon.</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"justify\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:14pt; font-weight:600;\"><br /></p>\n"
"<p align=\"justify\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt; font-weight:600;\">With Plot Twist, you can:</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"justify\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt; font-weight:600;\">- Look inside your dataset</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"justify\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt; font-weight:600;\">- Visualize it by choosing any possible diagrams of any columns</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"justify\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt; font-weight:600;\">- Find out specific calculation of any column</span></p></body></html>", None))
        self.homeToolbar.setWindowTitle(_translate("HomeWindow", "toolBar", None))
        self.actionOpenDataset.setText(_translate("HomeWindow", "Open Dataset", None))
        self.actionOpenDataset.setStatusTip(_translate("HomeWindow", "Open dataset to visualize it.", None))
        self.actionOpenDataset.setShortcut(_translate("HomeWindow", "Ctrl+O", None))
        self.actionHowTo.setText(_translate("HomeWindow", "How To", None))
        self.actionHowTo.setToolTip(_translate("HomeWindow", "How To Do This?", None))
        self.actionHowTo.setStatusTip(_translate("HomeWindow", "Instructions on how this app works.", None))
        self.actionHowTo.setShortcut(_translate("HomeWindow", "F1", None))
        self.actionAbout.setText(_translate("HomeWindow", "About", None))
        self.actionAbout.setToolTip(_translate("HomeWindow", "About", None))
        self.actionAbout.setStatusTip(_translate("HomeWindow", "Description and message by creator.", None))
        self.actionAbout.setShortcut(_translate("HomeWindow", "F2", None))

    def showHowto(self):
        HowToDialog = QtGui.QDialog()
        hui = Ui_HowToDialog()
        hui.setupUi(HowToDialog)
        HowToDialog.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())

import resources_rc

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    HomeWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_HomeWindow()
    ui.setupUi(HomeWindow)
    HomeWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And this is the dialog i tried to pop up. It's supposed to show HowTo dialog when the icon on toolbar is triggered.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'howto.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.11.4
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_HowToDialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, HowToDialog):
        HowToDialog.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("HowToDialog"))
        HowToDialog.resize(585, 242)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("Consolas"))
        HowToDialog.setFont(font)
        HowToDialog.setAcceptDrops(False)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8(":/resources/howto.png")), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        HowToDialog.setWindowIcon(icon)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(HowToDialog)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout"))
        self.howtoBrowser = QtGui.QTextBrowser(HowToDialog)
        self.howtoBrowser.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("howtoBrowser"))
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.howtoBrowser)

        self.retranslateUi(HowToDialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(HowToDialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, HowToDialog):
        HowToDialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("HowToDialog", "How To Do This?", None))
        self.howtoBrowser.setHtml(_translate("HowToDialog", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'Consolas\'; font-size:7.5pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p align=\"justify\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt;\">How to insert your dataset:</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"justify\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt;\">1. Click </span><span style=\" font-size:12pt; font-weight:600;\">Open Dataset </span><span style=\" font-size:12pt;\">icon.</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"justify\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt;\">2. Click </span><span style=\" font-size:12pt; font-weight:600;\">Browse </span><span style=\" font-size:12pt;\">and select your dataset.</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"justify\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt;\">3. Note that the dataset has to be a .csv file.</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"justify\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt;\">4. Click </span><span style=\" font-size:12pt; font-weight:600;\">Insert File </span><span style=\" font-size:12pt;\">button.</span></p>\n"
"<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt;\">5. Your dataset visualization window will appear, and you can start to visualize it.</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"justify\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:12pt;\"><br /></p>\n"
"<p align=\"justify\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt;\">Happy visualizing :)</span></p></body></html>", None))


import resources_rc

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    HowToDialog = QtGui.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_HowToDialog()
    ui.setupUi(HowToDialog)
    HowToDialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

As you can see, this is the function i define to show the second window:

```
def showHowto(self):
    HowToDialog = QtGui.QDialog()
    hui = Ui_HowToDialog()
    hui.setupUi(HowToDialog)
    HowToDialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And i have connected it with the action toolbar with `self.actionHowTo.triggered.connect(self.showHowto)`.

When i run it, it displays `QCoreApplication::exec: The event loop is already running`. Can somebody tell me what's wrong and the solution? Thanks before!

Comment: First of all, it really helps if you could post a "minimal example", e.g. a short piece of code that is sufficient to reproduce your problem. Second, I first had a hard time to understand how your question title is connected to your problem.  Now about your problem: I think you just have to get rid of ``sys.exit(app.exec_())`` in ``showHowTo``.

Comment: Noted, this is the first time i asked a question here. I tried that, but the second window popup and disappears immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar trouble when starting with pyqt.
You should create another class for the dialog window like so:

```
#!python3
'''docs'''
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from _apps.PyUi import DialogUi


class DialogApp(QDialog, DialogUi.Ui_DialogApp):
    """Dialog class"""

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)


def main(self):
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = DialogApp()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The main i included for easy testing...
The next part is in the main window just the slot connected with action:

```
def openDialog(self):

    self.dialog= DialogApp(self)
    self.dialog.show()
```

The part which you need to be careful about is who is the parent to the dialog, if `None` is parent like in my example the dialog will get a separate tab on the task bar and can be instantiated as many times as you click the `action`, assuming the dialog itself is modeless.
If you pass the `mainwindow` (`self`) to the dialog, which is recommended in most cases concerning dialog windows, the main will be the parent, by default the dialog will be centered on main when it appears.

#### Edit:

Also you need and can have only one `QApplication` active, all the windows shown and underlying methods and functions go through this initial `QApplication`, as far as I know.